# Show different content for registered members in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, themes

Okay so I currently have the following on show to all users that visit my WP site;

```
<div class="gravatar">
<?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id(); // Get the user ID
$size_avatar = 50; // Set the avatar size
$default_avatar = 'http://techyoucation.com/wp-content/themes/blank/images/avatar50.png';        // Set your default image url
echo get_avatar( $user_id, $size_avatar, $default_avatar ); // This prints the <img> tag     with correct avatar image url
?>
</div>
```

Now I would like this to only show to users who are signed-in to my site, and have different content to display for users who are no, for example

```
<div class="Register">
<p>Register</p>
</div>
```

How would I do this?

Thanks in advance

Aled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very simple function for it:

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>
    You're logged in.    
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="Register">
    <p>Register</p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in